# SharePoint web services GetListItems

Tags: vb.net, web-services, sharepoint

I'm making a windows form app to retrieve details about lists items.
I made the code and its running without error, but its returning 0 items even though there are items in the list
Can anyone tell me what the reason could be?

this is the xml response i get:

```
<listitems xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<rs:data ItemCount="0">
</rs:data>
</listitems>
```

here's the code:

```
Dim listService As New Lists()
listService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

listService.Url = "http://sitename/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"

    Dim xmlDoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
    Dim listName As String = "{83FEDC7E-1DDA-4A36-910A-D5140E51F0ED}"
    Dim viewName As String = "{77A23176-5CD4-46E9-BE57-AEB4D4279AD4}"
    Dim rowLimit As String = "150"
    Dim query As System.Xml.XmlNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query")
    Dim viewFields As System.Xml.XmlNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields")
    Dim queryOptions As System.Xml.XmlNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions")
    query.InnerXml = "<Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>lol</Value></Contains></Where></Query>"
    viewFields.InnerXml = ""
    queryOptions.InnerXml = "<ViewAttributes Scope='Recursive' />"
    Dim nodeListItems As XmlNode
    nodeListItems = listService.GetListItems(listName, viewName, query, viewFields, rowLimit, queryOptions, Nothing)
    TextBox1.Text += nodeListItems.OuterXml
```

**UPDATE:**
**The error was that I gave the domain and username in the same field of the credentials.**

Comment: How do you expect us to help you if you don't show us how you retrieve your items.

Comment: sorry about that, there's the code now
please help

Answer (score 1):

I believe this line is wrong :

```
query.InnerXml = "<Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>lol</Value></Contains></Where></Query>"
```

The node is "Query" itself, so this will ends with this xml :

```
<Query><Query>
      <Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>lol</Value></Contains></Where>
 </Query></Query>
```

Comment: its still not returning the items

Comment: A quick guess, remove the curly brackets around the list name and view name. It's actually a string, and I have vague memory of issues when using brackets.

Comment: I tried that but its still not working
Do u think it could be something wrong with the lists permissions or something?